# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar y leer una base de datos SQLite (con datos previos) en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, kotlin, base-de-datos, android-room

No sé si el título ha sido claro, no trato de leer y escribir en una BD como hacemos de normal, hasta ahí no hay ningún problema. Hablo de **guardar una BD con datos en la propia aplicación y poder acceder a ella**, estamos utilizando **Kotlin + ROOM**. Y me parece que este es uno de los mayores retos que se nos pone por delante.

Estaba pensando si teníamos que hacer un monton de inserts si es la primera vez que se abre la aplicación. Sin embargo, si se pudiese crear y rellenar la BD en el PC y luego simplemente arrastrar a la carpeta RAW sería de gran utilidad. De momento no tanteamos el usar un servidor, sino que cada dispositivo tenga la BD en local, con la ventaja de que funcione offline.

PD: si me ayudais subiré una aplicación avanzada a PlayStore con todo lo que voy recopilando bien explicado, y hasta os puedo poner en los créditos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anteriormente usando `SQLite`, la mejor opción era usar [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) que era capaz de leer tu base de datos la cual agregabas dentro del folder `/assets`; pero ahora con la introducción de `Room` esto no es un problema ya que  nativamente soporta el uso de [**bases de datos prepobladas**](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate).

> Para autocompletar una base de datos de Room a partir de un archivo de
> base de datos empaquetado previamente que está en cualquier lugar del
> directorio `assets/` de la app, llama al método `createFromAsset()`
> del objeto `RoomDatabase.Builder` antes de llamar a `build()`.

Ahora puedes crear tu base de datos, agregarla en el folder `/assets` y leerla de esta forma mediante el método [**databaseBuilder()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Room#databaseBuilder(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20java.lang.String)).

ejemplo, suponiendo que tu base de datos `"Information.db"` se encuentra dentro de `/assets/databases` de esta forma puedes adquirir la instancia de la base de datos:

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Information.db")
.createFromAsset("databases/Information.db")
.build()
```

Comment: **¡Muchísimas gracias!**
Ahora no puedo probarlo, pero en unos días haré y haremos pruebas a fondo para ver que tan bien funciona, si quieres que te ponga en los créditos de la aplicación tal como dije dime tu nombre, acrónimo o lo que quieras.
La aplicación se llama Pruebas 1 - P1, adjuntaré el link más adelante.

Comment: Pregunto para salir de dudas, ¿en el caso de usar `createFromAsset()` la App usará como BD `databases/Information.db` o creará una base de datos nueva en la carpeta interna `data` del dispositivo? Es una de las dudas planteadas en [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/387079/29967) y que la documentación no aclara. Si se crea una BD nueva habría dos bases de datos en la App y esto no es buena idea, sobre todo cuando queremos precargar bases de datos grandes. Es una especie de duplicidad de información ocupando espacio en el dispositivo.

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas. En caso de no encontrar la BD en la ruta indicada simplemente falla. Otra cosa interesante es que si borras los datos de la APP desde las opciones, la BD volverá a su estado original con todos los datos que tenía inicialmente. Ah, se me olvidaba, adjunto la APP de pruebas que hice para cacharrear. [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codigobase.pruebas1&gl=ES) y [GitHub](https://github.com/CarlosAguirreV/Pruebas1)
Un saludo, espero que esto responda a tu duda.