# ¿Cómo precargar una base de datos en Android para trabajar con Room?

Tags: android, room

Estoy intentando dar persistencia a los datos de mi aplicación mediante el uso de Room. Actualmente mis datos se encuentran en una base de datos MySQL alojada en un servidor remoto y la idea es **trasladarla localmente al dispositivo**. Se trata de una base de datos grande...

Estuve leyendo el apartado [*Cómo autocompletar la base de datos de Room*](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate) donde se explica que podría precargar la base de datos desde un archivo que podría estar en la carpeta `assets` de mi proyecto o en un archivo externo.

Mi idea es migrar mi base de datos de MySQL a SQLite, crear un archivo `.db` y colocarlo en `assets` para luego precargar los datos en la aplicación. Ahí surge mi duda precisamente: el archivo que se generará será grande  y no tendría sentido tenerlo en `assets` una vez la base de datos haya sido creada (supongo que se crea una base de datos nueva en la carpeta interna `data` del dispositivo).

La documentación no explica nada sobre mi duda: ¿qué ocurre con ese archivo que se coloca en `assets` una vez es generada la base de datos? ¿se borra de forma automática o debo borrarlo de forma manual? ¿tendría que procurar de algún modo que la base de datos autocomplete únicamente la primera vez que se abre la aplicación? ¿Hay un modo más simple de hacer lo que quiero?

No sé por donde empezar en este punto, por lo que abro esta pregunta con la esperanza de obtener alguna respuesta.

Comment: Si la base de datos queda agregada en Assets seria parte de tu apk y si es grande como dices el apk para descargarlo tambien tendria el mismo problema. Porque no tomar esos datos desde una API y se agreguen despues de la app instalada?

Comment: @RamiroBarone buen punto en el que no había pensado (meterla en `assets` haría crecer el tamaño inicial de la App, aunque la idea era **borrar el archivo** una vez ocurra el autocompletar o precarga). Había pensado también en migrarla desde el servidor, imagino que habría que programar un sincronizador o algo parecido para tales fines. En ese caso mi preocupación sería la carga en el servidor (es un hosting compartido y varios miles de usuarios descargando la BD sobre todo cuando se lanzan nuevas versiones de la App ¿? podrían bloquear mi BD/servidor remoto que además sirve una página web ).

Comment: Con que lenguaje lo trabajas? en mi caso lo hago con c# y xamarin. ahi te podria ayudar a hacer algo rapido. Si la app la usarian miles de usuario estamos hablando de una app que deberia tener un buen soporte de hardware detras.

Comment: @RamiroBarone es una App para Android programada en Java desde Android Studio. La App se descarga desde Play Store. Actualmente funciona, pero necesita conexión a internet para mostrar la información. La idea es que los usuarios puedan usarla cuando no tengan internet, por eso lo de hacer persistir los datos en el dispositivo mediante una BD.

Comment: Actualmente mantengo una app con BD para que funcione Offline, y lo hago con SQLite, el usuario lo descarga todo despues de instalar la app, este trabajo lo hice para dos multinacionales. Respondiendo a tu comentario sobre la respuesta de que nunca lo hiciste, no es algo complicado realizarlo. Te diria que le eches un vistazo a SQLite, es facil de crear las tablas y facil de hacer CRUD.

Comment: En mi caso, cuando agarre el proyecto le hice cambios para que la descarga fuera multi hilos y de esa manera le ahorre 80% del tiempo a estar disponible. Podrias considerarlo para tu proyecto.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Room usa SQLite. Es simplemente una capa de abstracción que simplifica bastante el trabajo permitiendo por ejemplo escribir consultas con la sintaxis SQL y sobre todo detecta cualquier error en las consultas o diseño de tablas en fase de compilación. Estuve haciendo pruebas con una BD sencilla y es realmente interesante, pero Room es parte de los Componentes de Arquitectura de Android que incorpora el estilo MVVM que tampoco domino, estoy apenas revisando los Codelabs y leyendo la documentación. Tampoco tendría claro cómo incorporar una sincronización si me decidiera por eso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112618/discussion-between-ramiro-barone-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0):

> Ahí surge mi duda precisamente: el archivo que se generará será grande
> y no tendría sentido tenerlo en assets una vez la base de datos haya
> sido creada (supongo que se crea una base de datos nueva en la carpeta
> interna data del dispositivo).

Si es demasiado grande lo cual implica un tamaño considerable para el .apk tal vez tendrías que considerar otra opción no leyendo una base de datos internamente en el proyecto.

> ¿qué ocurre con ese archivo que se coloca en assets una vez es
> generada la base de datos? ¿se borra de forma automática o debo
> borrarlo de forma manual?

La base de datos permanece ahí y esta no puede ser eliminada de  `assets/` .

Aquí alguien preguntaba sobre agregar una [base de datos Room prepoblada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380931/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-almacenar-y-leer-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-con-datos-previos-en-and/381232#381232).

Comment: En clase el año pasado una profesora nos explicó que era mejor tener archivos con las cosas que querías guardar en Room. El asunto es que estaba haciendo un pequeño juego rpg y tenía las listas de armas/armaduras/objetos... y quería saber cómo meter todo eso en Room la primera vez que creaba el juego. Y la profesora dijo que lo mejor era tener una clase estática con ArrayLists con todo lo que quieras meter en Room y al lanzar la actividad por primera vez, lanzar un hilo que vaya recorriendo esos ArrayLists y metiéndolos a la DB... Realmente sería buena idea, @Elenasys? Un saludo!

Comment: @Benito-B el problema aquí es que la BD con la que quiero trabajar es por lo menos 30 veces más grande que el tamaño de la propia App. Cuando genere el archivo y lo  meta en `assets` el tamaño inicial de la App se disparará. Estuve mirando algo sobre  [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) que podría ser interesante para sincronizar desde la BD remota. La verdad es que todos estos componentes son nuevos para mí y la sincronización es mi gran tarea pendiente en Android.

Comment: @A.Cedano el tamaño si es considerable!, no has pensado consultar/modificar la información mediante un WS y una bd externa?

Comment: @Elenasys así funciona actualmente de hecho. Pero los usuarios quieren persistencia en la App para poder usarla sin internet. He estado mirando tutoriales sobre sincronización entre una BD remota y una BD local y hay poca información sobre el tema (también en inglés).

Comment: @Benito-B puede ser mejor pero esto lo determina el tamaño de la base de datos, en este caso si necesitas una BD grande podría considerarse crear la app como  Android App Bundle

Comment: @A.Cedano Tuve el caso de una app que descargaba datos considerablemente, querían datos "offline" y los datos cambiaban continuamente, después de un análisis de pros/contras que se les mostró optaron por aceptar no tener datos "offline" una excelente opción es usar Firebase Realtime Database https://firebase.google.com/docs/database pero aquí el "problema" para muchos ( me incluyo) es que implica costo jeje.

Comment: @Elenasys he pensado también en esa opción, de hecho el contenido de algunos módulos de mi App es servido desde Firebase Firestore. El problema como bien dices es el costo y el *offline* de Firebase no resuelve mi problema (para tener cierto contenido sin conexión tienes que haber leído al menos una vez con conexión ese documento). Además Firebase creo que tiene un límite para guardar offline. Mi App maneja datos de varias tablas pero que es creado de forma dinámica de acuerdo a una fecha dada.

Comment: Estuve leyendo un poco más sobre el amplio tema de Android JetPack (que compone Room, LiveData, WorkManager y otros) y sobre el patrón MVVM, y casi me estoy decidiendo por una sincronización periódica de mi base de datos remota usando WorkManager (algo así como ir volcando la BD poco a poco en la BD local del dispositivo). Leí [este tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/periodic-tasks-with-android-workmanager-c901dd9ba7bc) y se parece bastante a lo que quiero lograr. En cuanto pueda me lanzaré por esa vía de solución y dejo saber si ha funcionado.